# Woocommerce multisite (product)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, multisite

I created a network of sites after activating the network of `wordpress`. I also installed on the network `woocommerce` to manage the purchasing system.

Now I need to connect the database `woocommerce` main site with one of it's sub-sites so that the `subsites` see the `categories` and `product` attributes of the main site.

**Question :**

when I go to add a product default `categories` and `attributes` are loaded from the current site but I need to take this data from the main site.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

get it from the wp_terms and wp_woocommerce_attributes_taxonomies